# Drupal 7 Custom Page shown only for logged-in users

Tags: 7

My problem is that, I need to create a new Page (path f.e. //panel), but I want there only logged-in users. If user is not logged in, he should be redirected to login form. I was trying to do it with Custom Pages, but I dont know how to do it, I can create variant only with HTTP response code, and its working good, but I dont know how to show content of this page, it's simply redirected me if I'm not logged in or displaying, that page is not found if I'm logged in.
Do you know a solution for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a custom page, so you should use [user_is_anonymous()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_is_anonymous/7) in the calback of the page.

For example:

`$form['custom_path'] = array(
  'page callback' => 'some_random_function',
);
function some_random_function() {
 if(user_is_anonymous()) { 
  //call the login block
 }
 else {
  // What ever u want.
 }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but can I do it non-programmatically? I want to have as little as it's possible custom code. Of course there will be some my custom functions and modules, but is it possible to set it in drupal without my code?
Or, if it's not possible, can you tell me on which hook I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without custom code if you like by using panels. Create a custom panel for the path that you want. Then add a variation so you have 2 panels variations, the first one with a context for logged in users that shows them the content you want to show them. Then you can have the other variation be a http response (302) and set them to redirect to /user so they will have to login.

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be accomplished using [Rules:](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)

> The Rules module allows site administrators to define conditionally
>   executed actions based on occurring events (known as reactive or ECA
>   rules). It's a replacement with more features for the trigger module
>   in core and the successor of the Drupal 5 workflow-ng module.

Set up a new Rule:

Trigger: Drupal Initializes

Condition: Check Path: panel (the path)

Action: Page Redirect: user/login